# [ROS2] Is there a way for a node to subscribe to existing topics?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is extremely easy to create a topic, just by publishing a message to a nonexistent topic would cause ROS2 to create that topic for you, as seen in [this tutorial](http://www.theconstructsim.com/ros2-in-5-mins-005-how-to-work-with-ros2-topics-from-the-command-line/)

However, is there a way to make an existing node subscribe to an existing topic?

The tutorial above showed a way to create a new node to subscribe to a topic, by simply using the command `ros2 topic echo /<TOPIC NAME>`. This created a new node, `/_ros2cli_25438`, which I assume is the command line, subscribing to the topic `/barbarians`, which is being published to by the existing node `/_ros2cli_publisher_std_msgs_String`.

However, is there a command to have an existing node subscribe to an existing topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324598/%5Bros2%5D-is-there-a-way-for-a-node-to-subscribe-to-existing-topics?/) by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2019-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> However, is there a way to make an existing node subscribe to an existing topic?

A node can subscribe to a topic whether it exists or not. If it doesn't, then after the node subscribes it will effectively exist.

> However, is there a command to have an existing node subscribe to an existing topic?

If a node's source is not written so that it subscribes to a topic, then no, you can't make it subscribe to a topic via an external command.

If you want to write a node that can subscribe to a topic on demand, then you can do that with the following steps:

- Have the node subscribe to a topic with a message type that is something like the following:

  ```
  std_msgs/String topic_name
  ```
- When the node receives a message on the topic, it would subscribe to the specified topic.
- Use `rostopic pub /blag std_msgs/String 'topic_to_subscribe_to'` to tell the node to subscribe to a new topic.

The above makes some assumptions:

- The topic will have a type fixed at compile time, or you are using `rclpy` and have written your callback such that it can handle in some way any message type that arrives.
- The node's subscriber callback is reentrant, such that multiple topics receiving messages at once using the same callback is not a problem, or you can guarantee that your node will only ever subscribe to or receive messages on one topic at a time.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
@Geoff: your answer is high-level, so it doesn't really matter, but the OP tagged this with `ros2` and you're referring to `rospy` which is the ROS 1 client library. Should that have been `rclpy`?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-06-04**:
Gah sorry. I need sleep. Yes, it should be `rclpy`. Although as you say, the answer doesn't change for ROS 1 or ROS 2.

**Comment by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on 2019-06-04**:
Thank you very much.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
As a general comment on this topic btw: @wan_da: you may want to look into *remapping*. If you're worried about nodes not subscribing to topics that exist -- but perhaps they are subscribing to topics with the same type but a different name -- and still want to connect nodes, you can remap whatever topic they are subscribing to, to something else. I've tried to clarify how this works in ROS 1 in #q303611. That Q&A also links to a ROS 2 article about the subject.

It does have its uses, but using a topic to instruct a node to subscribe to another topic seems like an anti-pattern to me.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-06-04**:
I definitely agree it's an anti-pattern and not something I would recommend doing. A node's interface, in terms of the topics, services, actions and parameters it interacts with, needs to be known and well-documented. Creating a node that subscribes to the message type you are interested in and remapping it at launch time is the correct approach.